# How can I prove that the first three decimal digits of a real number between 0 and 1 can be equal to the reciprocal of 2 to the power of that number?

Tags: proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation, real-numbers

This is the challenge problem at the end of Chapter 1 of Solow's *How to Read and Do Proofs*.

*The problem:*

> Find a counter-example to the following statement:  “If *x* is a
>   positive real number between 0 and 1, then the first three decimal
>   digits of *x* are not equal to the first three decimal digits of $2^{-x}$.

*My attempt*:

- The hypothesis *A* is that *x* is a real number between 0 and 1.
- The conclusion *B* is that the first three decimal digits of *x* are equal to the first three decimal digits of $2^{-x}$.
- A possible key question is, "How can I show that the first three decimal digits of a real number between 0 and 1 is identical to first three decimal digits of the reciprocal of 2 to the power of that number?

I've tried to reformulate this as a problem with graphs. I graphed the horizontally flipped version of *f*(*x*) = $2^{x}$, then looked at the graph between 0 and 1.

But I'm not sure how to continue; it's possible I need to review the necessary background knowledge.

What topic in mathematics should I study to solidify my background knowledge to learn more relevant information for answering this question? If this isn't necessary, could I receive a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: what can you say about $x-y$ if $x$ and $y$ have identical first three decimal digits? How can you strenghten this property to get the inverse implication?

Comment: If $x$ is sufficiently close to the unique root of the equation $x=2^{-x}$, the first three (or more, if we so wish) decimals of $x$ and $2^{-x}$ will coincide.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm unsure how to use this info, possibly due to my misunderstanding of the definition of a unique root. But $f(x)$ = $2^{-x}$ does not approach 0 as $x$ either approaches 0 or 1 ($(f(x)$ approaches 1 and 0.5 respectively). (A [Yahoo Answer here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091203170017AAyteGT) states that it's a value that makes a function equal to 0.)

Comment: Look [here](http://www.emathhelp.net/notes/algebra-1/linear-equations/definition-of-the-equation-roots-of-the-equation/), or at the answer of Christian Blatter.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you, I understand now! So if $x = 2^{-x}$, then $0 = x -  2^{-x}$. Now, let $f(x) = 0$. If $f(x) = 0$, then $x$ must equal $f(x)$. As $f(x)$ is a continuous function, $f(0) = -1$, and $f(1) = 1/2$, then there must be a value of $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$ between 0 and 1 by the Intermediate Value Theorem - as stated by Chrstian Blatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told to produce a counterexample to a somewhat  arbitrary statement. The circumstances suggest that there is such a counterexample. How to find it? Why should some $x\in\ ]0,1[\ $ have a similar decimal representation as $2^{-x}$? The natural reason is that in fact $x=2^{-x}$. Therefore let's prove that there is such an $x$. Unless some trouble of the kind $0.6299997$ turns up it then should be possible to name a clear cut (i.e., having finite decimal expansion) $x$ that is a counterexample to the alleged claim.

The function $f(x):=x-2^{-x}$ has values $f(0)=-1$, $f(1)={1\over2}$, hence at least one zero $\xi\in\ ]0,1[\ $. It turns out that $\xi\doteq0.641$. Entering $x:=0.641$ into a pocket calculator gives $2^{-x}\doteq0.641268$, establishing $x$ as a counterexample to the alleged claim.

Answer (score 3):

I started with $x=0.123$ and got $2^{-x}=0.918$

Then I considered $x=0.918$ and got $2^{-x}=0.529$

And went on applying the same function so I got the sequence

$0.123,\;0.918,\;0.529,\;0.693,\;0.618,\;0.651,\;0.636,\;0.643,\;0.640,\;0.641,\;0.641,\;0.641,\;\ldots$

Hope this is useful
The fixed point $x=0.641$ is the counterexample

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but how do we know this recursion is convergent?

Comment: Yes it was indeed a stupid question. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @VladeKR As derivative $f'(x)=-2^{-x} \log 2$ satisfies $|f'(x)|<1$ on $[0,1]$ then the function satisfies the Lipschitz condition and has a fixed point such that $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can construct an easy counter example using the fact that as $x \rightarrow 0$, $2^{-x} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: No, because as $x \to 0^+$, the first three digits of $x$ become $000$ while those of $2^{-x}$ become $999$.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but @Adayah is right - I've verified the comment by plugging in values.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! I ignored the minus sign. But actually you can show that there exist a solution for $x = 2^{-x}$ between 0 and 1, since $f(x) = x - 2^{-x}$ is less than 0 at $x = 0$ and greater than 0 at $x=1$, intermediate value theorem suggest that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = 0$.